# In Python, given that there is a matrix, how do I print a slice of it?

Tags: python

Let me first outline the overall context of the problem at hand, through the following code snippet.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
df.as_matrix
```

The desired matrix [100 rows x 785 columns] is output.

I am having difficulty in outputting(using print()) a row of the above matrix.

I tried the following, but in vain:

```
print(df[0])
print(df[:, 0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `as_matrix()` is array of arrays. So following code should work:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
matrix = df.as_matrix()
print(matrix[0]) # out put first row.
print(matrix[3:5] # output from 3 row up to 4 row.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific row where the row index is equal `A`:

```
df.iloc[A, :785]
```

In general, you can use `df.iloc` to slice from a pandas dataframe using the idnex. For example, to slice rows from up to 100 and columns up to 785 you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("abc.csv")
df = df.iloc[:100, :785]
df.as_matrix()
```

If you want to slice the first row after converting to matrix, you are working with a list of lists, so you can do that as follows:

```
print(df.as_matrix()[1,:])
```

Here is a working example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

st = """
col1|col2|col3 
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
"""

pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|")
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), sep="|")
print("print first row from a matrix") 
print(df.as_matrix()[0,:])
print("print one column")
print(df.iloc[:2,1]) 
print("print a slice")
print(df.iloc[:2,:])
print("print one row")
print(df.iloc[1,:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing parenthesis:

```
df.as_matrix()[0]
```

---

Or you can use:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html

.head(n=5) Returns first n rows

```
df.head(1).as_matrix()
```